# Data too long for column 'descr' at row 2

Tags: mysql

When I try this sql statement to execute

```
update claim cl set search_field = (select  concat(cl.claim_description,' ', cl.legal_basis,' ',co.name) from contact co where cl.probable=1 and cl.search_field is null and co.id=cl.contact_id)
```

I get error above, and there is no column named `descr`. There is column named `claim_description` but it isn't `descr`

Does anyone have hint?
Thank you

Comment: If you try only the select part, does that work?
     select concat(cl.claim_description,' ', cl.legal_basis,' ',co.name) 
     from contact co where cl.probable=1 and cl.search_field is null and co.id=cl.contact_id

Comment: Yes if I add claim cl in from of "select". It is clear it won't work without that as we don't have claim table in from of select.

Comment: Do you have any triggers defined? (`SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'claim';`)

Comment: Yes Matt you are right, that was problem. Trigger was reporting that error. I turned those off ran update command and now it is all OK. I did what I itened to do . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Off course I turned triggers on again :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a correlated subquery in an UPDATE statement try:

```
UPDATE claim cl, contact co
SET cl.search_field = CONCAT (cl.claim_description,' ',cl.legal_basis,' ',co.NAME)          
WHERE cl.probable = 1
    AND cl.search_field IS NULL
    AND co.id = cl.contact_id
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I get same error. It comes pretty much faster than before but I still get that error.

Comment: Query starts with execution but it fails, so it is not problem with syntax or something like that.

Comment: What is the field types/lengths of claim_description, legal_basis, name, and search_field. Is this just an instance of `search_field` not being large enough to support the concatenated result?

Comment: Triggers were problem. One variable called descr in trigger was too short and trigger was reporting that. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I found solution for this. Trigger on update was problem it was trying to update variable descr which was too short. It looks like brushing teeth really helps in programming :)